# Selection Shortcut for Adobe Audition

Tags: sound, editing, adobe

I hope it is the right place to ask an Adobe Audition specific question.

I'm trying to get audio clips from a large audio file.

When I play and pause a sound in Adobe Audition's Editor using `Space`,  it shows two playheads, The current playhead and a temporary *dimmed* playhead for snapping purposes. You can jump to that previous playhead with "Q".

**I want to select the audio between those two playheads with a single shortcut.**

[image]

There is a way though. Here are the steps

```
1) Press "M" key to set a marker at the current playhead
2) Press "Q" to select the previous head 
3) Press "I" to make it an IN point 
4) Press "Alt+RightArrow" to select the recently created marker
5) Then Hit the "O" key to set the out point.
```

Needless to mention that then you have to delete the unwanted markers and there is no shortcut to do so either. I know its humiliating but Yes, one can get the selection.

I'm looking for a SINGLE shortcut for audio between current playhead to previous playhead.

Comment: This is one of those questions that is asking for a solution to a problem, but the original reason isn't clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this from an audio standpoint? What workflow is this activity part of?

Comment: As I said earlier, trying to get the audio clips from a large audio file. Basically I want to minimize mouse interaction because evertime I try to select with mouse, I can't end up with same piece of audio in selection. Sometimes, the clip I recently played goes off-screen. (I can go to previous point using Q) but then I'd loose the current point. Right now, my only hope is markers or I'm stuck with mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've searched the keyboard shortcuts so the next step is either some type of macro recorder within AA(?Like Cubase has?) or an external keyboard macro recorder. You could then have a single shortcut key to kick off this list of shortcuts you posted.

I'm not sure about deleting the markers, but surely the in/out markers would just relocate on the next use of the shortcut list? I'm not sure.

The reason this question is confusing, is that this is not what those markers were designed for. And the normal way to extract audio is less 'rushed' and more precise. On a batch extract, there are usually some definable markers within the signal to allow for automation.

Good luck with it.

Comment: I've been trying to create a native Apple Script Service using automator for this workflow but the current os `mojave` has serious issues with Automator workflows for security reasons. I've tried my best to authorize it but to no avail. I'll see it some other time.